# How to fix a random "java.lang.NullPointerException at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlHierBinding.bringNodeToRangeKeyPath" error

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I'm using oracle-adf to create a webapp,and I have parent and children entities, so what is happening is that I'm getting the below error randomly and I'm not able to reproduce the scenario.

I am using this library https://github.com/marksh222/universalTaskFlow/blob/master/Rcore/Global/src/com/rcore/global/jsf/JSFUtils.java with an error getting from the line FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), and after putting logs inside every function in my backing bean and inside every function inside the library the error is occurring after exiting my functions, so I'm guessing that the error isn't invoked by my functions. :

```
            [2019-04-24T10:19:29.476+03:00] [AdminServer] [WARNING] [] [oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.context.RichExceptionHandler] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: WDAHER] [ecid: fd85d3cb-14a7-40f2-a2d2-62ea888e02e7-0000055e,0] [APP: ProviderApp] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] [DSID: 0000MdE9WTc0ZrwN0EFg6F1SjybR00000B] ADF_FACES-60098:Faces lifecycle receives unhandled exceptions in phase RESTORE_VIEW 1[[
            java.lang.NullPointerException
                            at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlHierBinding.bringNodeToRangeKeyPath(JUCtrlHierBinding.java:1513)
                            at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlHierBinding.bringNodeToRangeKeyPath(FacesCtrlHierBinding.java:123)
                            at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.RowDataManager.setRowKey(RowDataManager.java:152)
                            at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlHierBinding$FacesModel.setRowKey(FacesCtrlHierBinding.java:932)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCollection.setRowKey(UIXCollection.java:563)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXTable.setRowKey(UIXTable.java:794)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCollection.invokeOnComponent(UIXCollection.java:1371)
                            at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.data.RichTable.invokeOnComponent(RichTable.java:263)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.invokeOnComponent(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:262)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.invokeOnComponent(UIXInclude.java:167)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.invokeOnComponent(UIXInclude.java:167)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.invokeOnComponent(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:262)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.invokeOnComponent(UIXInclude.java:167)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnNamingContainerComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2139)
                            at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.invokeOnComponent(UIXRegion.java:447)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnChildrenComponents(UIXComponentBase.java:2070)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIXComponentBase.java:2200)
                            at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1503)
                            at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:714)
                            at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._fixClientIds(LifecycleImpl.java:1368)
                            at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._fixIds(LifecycleImpl.java:593)
                            at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeRestoreViewAfterPhaseListenerLogic(LifecycleImpl.java:538)
                            at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeAfterPhaseLogic(LifecycleImpl.java:466)
                            at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:381)
                            at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:227)
                            at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
                            at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:207)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
                            at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
                            at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:354)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:232)
                            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
                            at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
                            at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$3.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:172)
                            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                            at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
                            at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
                            at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:110)
                            at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilterInternal(JpsAbsFilter.java:273)
                            at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:147)
                            at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
                            at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:248)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3701)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
                            at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
                            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
                            at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
                            at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
                            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
                            at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
                            at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
                            at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
                            at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
                            at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
                            at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
                            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
                            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
```

I already tried every possible scenario to reproduce the error but with no clear scenario to help me solve the error.

Comment: Hey Wissam, try and set your log level for oracle.adfinternal and oracle.jbo to FINEST and reproduce. You'll get more detail on what component is triggering this error.

Comment: hello, thank you for your quick response i already had logs and the null pointer exception was getting from FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() which is also randomly throwing a null pointer Exception.

Comment: Could you update the question with the code where you are calling this FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()? Is this done in a bean ? in a standard adf component ? etc

Comment: we are using this library https://github.com/marksh222/universalTaskFlow/blob/master/Rcore/Global/src/com/rcore/global/jsf/JSFUtils.java  with an error getting from the line FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), and after putting logs inside every function in my backing bean the error is occurring after exiting them, so the error isn't invoked by my functions.

Comment: and I can post my bean and Jsf but they are too long and too distracting. but as i said the error is being thrown after exiting my bean functions.

Comment: Usually FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() is an issue that occur in an adf bean that don't have a well defined scope. (FacesContext need to exist in the scope where the adf been is called) So look this way, without more info i can't help you more than that. :)

Comment: thank you again for your comments, the error is occurring randomly after a while from loading the page with no exact time, and not on page loading. it seems as if the page is loosing the FacesContext after a while. also the scope of the bean is defined as view.

Comment: Ok so if it only occur after some time maybe it's your application module or web.xml who don't have the same session timeout value. The application module session would have timeout without notifying the user

Comment: we are using ejb jpa instead of business component so we are not using application module. but I configured web.xml to close the session after 3 minutes. does it make any difference ?